# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error Rails 5.0, Amazon S3, Direct upload with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to develop a form to upload a picture direct from Rails 5.0.1 app to Amazon s3 as per: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails instructions.

I am using the jQuery-File-Upload plugin as well as aws-sdk gem. When attempting to submit an image file, I get the error message:

*"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400."*

As I understand, this suggests an issue with CORS.

I have configured my CORS permission in my S3 bucket as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've tried replacing the origin with "*", tried each url individually, tried different headers, and seemingly tried every recommendation out there.

Additionally, my presigned post is set to 'public-read' :

```
  def set_s3_direct_post

@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET_NAME.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')

  end
```

And, incase there is any confusion, I'm not using Heroku.

Is anyone else attempting to use a similar upload method and run into the same error?

Thanks in advance for any help!